# PHP LEAP ORM query with table alias

Tags: php, kohana-3, kohana-orm

Currently I am using the LEAP ORM for kohana and am attempting to create some sql queries. These queries are going against an oracle database. I am able to connect and query this database successfully. However when I attempt to alias tables and reference columns using those alias, the syntax is not working. Below is what I currently have

```
     return $this->db->query("select HRB.PARENT_COMPANY 
FROM COMPANY_TABLE HRB 
INNER JOIN 
OTHER_TABLE BTR 
HRB.ID = BTR.WID 
WHERE HRB.NAME LIKE '".$VAL."%;");
```

It doesnt seem to like HRB.PARENT

Error message

```
ErrorException [ Warning ]: oci_execute(): ORA-00904: &quot;GPR&quot;.&quot;GIS_PROP_FCNB_1&quot;: invalid identifier
MODPATH\leap\classes\Base\DB\Oracle\DataReader\Standard.php [ 57 ]
52          throw new Throwable_SQL_Exception('Message: Failed to query SQL statement. Reason: :reason', array(':reason' => $reason));
53      }
54      if ( ! is_integer($mode)) {
55          $mode = 32;
56      }
57      if ( ! oci_execute($command, $mode)) {
58          $error = @oci_error($command);
59          $reason = (is_array($error) AND isset($error['message']))
60              ? $error['message']
61              : 'Unable to perform command.';
62          throw new Throwable_SQL_Exception('Message: Failed to query SQL statement. Reason: :reason', array(':reason' => $reason));
```

If table alias is removed the following error is thrown

```
ErrorException [ Warning ]: oci_execute(): ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

Comment: Does it work without the table alias, i.e. `COMPANY_TABLE.PARENT_COMPANY`?  If that's actual SQL, you're [doing it wrong](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp); it should be `FROM COMPANY_TABLE AS HRB`

Comment: I appreciate the assistance. But the tables are being aliased correctly. http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/alias.php

Comment: It might not be PL/SQL.  ORMs typically do not use vendor-specific syntax.  Try the `AS` variant.

Comment: Still an issue. The IDE I am using is complaining as early as the first time I use ALIAS.COLUMN

Comment: Apparently LEAP ORM does not support alias usage.  Really, you shouldn't need it.

Comment: If I dont use it I get "column ambiguously defined".

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://spadefoot.github.io/kohana-orm-leap/tutorials/building-sql-statements/) says that Table Aliases are not supported in DB_ORM.

Try this:

```
return $this->db->query("select COMPANY_TABLE.PARENT_COMPANY 
FROM COMPANY_TABLE
INNER JOIN OTHER_TABLE COMPANY_TABLE.ID = OTHER_TABLE.WID 
WHERE OTHER_TABLE.NAME LIKE '".$VAL."%;");
```

Comment: Actually that will not work, because PARENT_COMPANY is in both tables. And without aliasing the columns will be ambiguous.